# Parameter interpretation when running jobs

Tags: powershell

```
$h = "host1.example.com"
$code = {
  $(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ComputerName $h)
}
$timeout = 5
$jobstate = $(Wait-Job -Job ($job = $(Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code)) -Timeout $timeout)
$wmicomobj = $(Receive-Job -Job $job)
```

Why does the codeblock above raise the following error?

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or
empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command
again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I would like to use this to implement a timeout when getting WMI objects for multiple hosts in a loop. But first I need to get the results via job execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables defined in the global scope of your script are not available inside the scriptblock unless you use the `using` qualifier:

```
$code = {
  Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ComputerName $using:h
}
```

or pass them in as arguments, like this:

```
$code = {
  Param($hostname)
  Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ComputerName $hostname
}
$jobstate = Wait-Job -Job ($job = $(Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -ArgumentList $h)) -Timeout $timeout
```

or like this:

```
$code = {
  Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ComputerSystem" -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ComputerName $args[0]
}
$jobstate = Wait-Job -Job ($job = $(Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -ArgumentList $h)) -Timeout $timeout
```